# " rake aborted! unknown attribute: date " while running rake db:seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

rake aborted!
unknown attribute: date

I am finally able to migrate my database content but encounter this unfortunate error.

Is it because the date attributes are older than the actual new database or something? Date is not specifically defined in my model but obviously the data was in the old database before and def not manually entered. I think t.timestamp takes care of that initialization, so i guess the question is why I cannot seed into my database? Any ideas

My seed file looks something like this:

```
Indication.create([
  { :name => "general", :date => "2012-11-09 17:36:25" },
```

Comment: Is date db column on your Indication model or are you using timestamps? Could always use Time.now instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `Indication` model does not have a `date` field. Do you need to [create a migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration) to add one?

Answer (score 0):

So just in case someone encounters the same problem, here is my solution:

My seed:dump had extracted the data in this case "2012-11-09 17:36:25" and assigned it the variable "date". While I am still not sure why this happened it has to do with the t.timestamp  command.

t.timestamp creates 2 variables:

1. created_at
2. updated_at

The side file had the 2012-11-09 17:36:25 as "date" variable, which is a reasonable guess based on the format, but nevertheless it is wrong for the Rails application standard. My tables had only two variables that were datetime format which are the ones I named above.

I opened the seeds file and replaced all the ":date" for ":created_at" and it solved the problem. updated_at then acquired the value automatically (updated at was not transferred from my old database to this new one).

The created_as data did transfer and was correct. updated_at acquired the same value in all the data (I noticed it was the date and time and performed the rake db:seed:load command.